# Is T<'a>: 'b syntactic sugar for 'a: 'b?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, type-bounds

Trying to understand the meaning of binding a type by a lifetime in a where clause.

My current understanding is that it desugars to lifetime bounds for every lifetime the type is parametrized in.

For instance `&'a T: 'b` would desugar to `'a: 'b` as `&` are parametrized in 1 lifetime, and `i32: 'a` desugars to nothing, since there are no lifetime parameters (so it always holds true).

Could someone with more insight into rustc implementation confirm this? If there are nuances/differences and these are not equivalent, please correct my understanding.

Example:

```rust
fn test<'a, T: ?Sized>(p: &'a T)
where
    &'a i32: 'static,
{
}

fn test2<'a, T: ?Sized>(p: &'a T)
where
    'a: 'static,
{
}

fn main() {
    let string = String::from("hello");
    test(&string);
    test2(&string);
}
```

Both calls fail with the same error. The i32 type used in the bound in `test` has nothing to do with concrete types I'm passing.

Comment: Please add a complete [mre] of the code you're talking about.

Comment: @Brian61354270 I don't want this question to turn into breaking down the meaning of one particular example, instead this is more of the compiler/semantics question of the Rust language.

Comment: Why on earth would syntactic sugar be **more verbose**?!? I think what you're actually asking is if the former implies the later‽ But it's not exactly clear if that's all you're asking.

Comment: Please add example code. You can still get at the compiler behaviour and semantics with a few short examples that illustrate your point.

Comment: @cafce25 I don't think it's more verbose in some instances! For example,
`Type<'a, 'b>: Trait1 + Trait2 + 'c + 'd + 'e`
is less verbose than
```Type<'a, 'b>: Trait1 + Trait2,
'a: 'c + 'd + 'e,
'b: 'c + 'd + 'e
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `T<'a>: 'b` is not syntax sugar or equivalent to `'a: b'`, it implies all references (also the unmentioned, invisible ones) in `T` have to live as long as well. So `&'a X: 'b` implies that `'a` has to outlive `'b` (`'a: 'b`), but additionally all references *in* `X` also have to outlive `'b`.

If a value is to be valid for a lifetime, all references in it also have to live at least as long or else you have an invalid value.

Comment: When you say 'implies', it sounds like there's more to it that just that. How is `&'a X: 'b` more than `'a: 'b`?

Comment: `X` can't contain any references that don't live as long as `'b` either, might be by being `'static` such as `i32` or because all references in `X` are also bound by `'b`.

Comment: The fact that X can be parametrized in lifetimes too doesn't contradict what I said about sugar either. It's the language of i32 is 'static that I don't follow. How can a type be 'static? i32: 'static only makes sense if we're saying all lifetime parameters of i32 (which is none) are bound by 'static. Talking about lifetimes with respect to types doesn't make sense imo.

Comment: When I say a type is static I mean that it fulfills the bound `T: 'static` that's pretty common lingo. An `i32` does so because it doesn't contain any references that are shorter than `'static` (by not containing any references at all).

Comment: The difference is that `T` might contain lifetime parameters that you can't see (at that level). So `&'a T: 'b` is not equivalent to `'a: 'b` it is stronger as it also requires potential invisible lifetimes inside of `T` to outlive `'b` as well.

Comment: @zabbir Another way of saying; If you can write `&'a T` then this is only valid if `T` and inner refs outlive `'a`. Since `'a: 'b` is already implied then `T` an inners outlive `'b` with the transitivity rule

Comment: @cafce25 could you please provide an example where `&'a T: 'b` is stronger than `'a: 'b`? Something that the first one does not permit and the second one does. Thanks!

Comment: @zabbir [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=672186622323ef0730322586aaeebe5b) and by extension [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=73878c536cf9856667a872683b96e769)